# Negative lookbehind not working correctly

Tags: regex

regex pattern(javascript and pcre)

```
<a href="(?<!#).*".*>(.*)<\/a>
```

This pattern should not select any html anchor tag of which the href attribute starts with a # symbol. But it matches the following code

```
<a href="#team">Team</a>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/16 - Does this work for you ? You can add closing anchor at end if you want. `^(?!\<a href="#)\<a href=.*<\/a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look-arounds are zero-width, meaning they don't consume any characters, making them only useful at the start and end of a pattern. `#team` is not preceded by `#`, so the first `.*` matches `#team`.

The way to write what you want is `"[^#].*"`. This means the first character in the quotes must not be `#`. One caveat here is that it will not match empty strings, but that's easy enough to add like so: `"([^#].*)?"`.